# I need to scan the same Cell in excel all the time

Tags: microsoft-excel, scanner, scanning

Hi I am scanning Bar Code Products into a spread sheet and when the bar code matches the log it shows a route which is great but after each scan Excel moves on to next cell
I need the scanner to always scan in same cell as that's where the lookup works from so how to i make excel stay in one cell all the time for the scanner

Comment: If you are not doing anything else with that particular excel sheet, then unprotect the cell, and protect the whole sheet. The enter/tab behavior will not move to the next cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The barcode scanner typically sends an <kbd>Enter</kbd> Or <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after each Scan.

This behaviour is normally configurable in the scanner and regarding to PeterH (thanx) in the comments you can even configure most scanners to stay in the cell and remove the cell content before the next scan.

The last time I worked with scanners (many years ago) that involved scanning a single or sequence of barcodes that programmed this function into the scanner.
The barcodes to scan could be found in the manual of the scanner.

If thats not possible or you do not know / find out, how to change the behaviour of your scanner, then you need to react on the change of the cell.

You can use the change event to watch this and simply go back to the entering cell. In the following example the cell would be A3, just change as needed:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, but OP would still be better configuring the scanner not to press enter/tab, just for efficiency

Comment: The problem is: If the scanner does NOT press enter / tab, then the cursor will stay in the  cell... and every subsequent scan will append the result to the cell... so then you need to make sure, that after each scan the complete content of the cell is selected... another VBA- code solution...

Comment: from my experience of working with scanners, there has always been an option to remain `in cell`  clearing existing data before a new entry is scanned, but I can't say for sure that the OPs scanner will have this option as they have not listed make and model

Comment: @PeterH: added your comment to the post. Thanx for helping!

Comment: The Scanner I am using is Inateck Barcode Scanner Bluetooth, Wireless, 15 continuous working days, 35m Range, Automatic Fast and Precise scanning, BCST-70 and I am unsure if it can be set to stay in cell

Comment: How and Where do I enter the code for the Cell to not move down once used as per 1st Answer please? such as this code Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
End Sub

Comment: The Scanner supplier has given me the info so that the scanner stays in same cell which is Great but what I need now is for the spread sheet to update when I scan a Bar-code which currently it does not so any advice how I get excel to do this please?

Comment: Please write a new question for that...